# Static DHCP and manual in raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi, raspbian-jessie, ethernet

What is the difference between static, dynamic and manual. what are the settings required to connect using WiFi and Ethernet in raspbian? Please tell in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iface eth0 inet static`: you can setup static IP

`iface eth0 inet manual`: create a network interface without an IP address.

For more information read [this](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration)

If you want to manage network configuration, you have to know that you have dhcpcd service active and so you have to manage two separate files:

`/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces`

if your purpose is manage ip on certain network, you have only to modify the first one like this:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.46.72
static routers=192.168.46.1
static domain_name_addresses=8.8.8.8
```

and so you have just setup static ip on wired connection

*Setup WiFi*

Add network info on `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
network={
    ssid="ESSID"
    psk="Your_wifi_password"
}
```

Add static ip on WiFi network `sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.46.72
static routers=192.168.46.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

So basically leave with no change `/etc/network/interfaces` file and manage only `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` if you want to setup static IP on wired or WiFi network, add your network credential on `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` if you need to connect via WiFi.